# Validate If A Value Is In Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to generate a random code, but before append it to the Google Sheet it needs to check if the code is already in the Sheet or not, if there is then it needs to re-random it again until there's no match. How to loop it until there's no match in Google Sheet? Your response will be appreciated.

Here's my .gs code:

```
function processForm2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var data = ws.getRange(5, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  var code = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
  var codeList = data.map(function(r){return r[0].toString(); });
  var position = codeList.indexOf(code);
  
  if(position < -1){
    ws.appendRow([code]);
  }else{
    var code = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
    ws.appendRow([code]);      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, how about looping when `position` is not `-1`? When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
var code = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
var codeList = data.map(function(r){return r[0].toString(); });
var position = codeList.indexOf(code);

if(position < -1){
  ws.appendRow([code]);
}else{
  var code = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
  ws.appendRow([code]);      
}
```

#### To:

```
var codeList = data.map(function(r){return r[0].toString(); });
var code;
do {
  code = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
  var position = codeList.indexOf(code);
} while (position > -1);
ws.appendRow([code]);
```

#### Reference:

- [while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while)